# Scaling SVG image element when image is another SVG file

Tags: svg

I am making a tool where I need a possibility to add an image into existing SVG. This image can be both Bitmap file and another SVG file. So I do it using  element, like this:

```
<image x="100" y="100" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="image.jpg">
```

I need this image to fit to width/height I specified (I don't care about the original size of an image), that's why I set preserveAspectRatio to "none". And it works fine with bitmaps. However when I try the same code with another SVG image, it is not scaled. The preserverAspectRatio description says that viewBox should be set on this image element, however it doesn't help - the image is not scaled.

Here is the code which, as far as I understand should work:

```
<image x="100" y="100" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="clock.svg">
```

And here is source of the clock.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Map">
<path d="M8.179,20.115c-0.478,0.277-0.642,0.889-0.365,1.366c0.275,0.479,0.889,0.642,1.365,0.366c0.479-0.275,0.643-0.888,0.367-1.367C9.27,20.004,8.658,19.84,8.179,20.115zM9.18,12.239c-0.479-0.276-1.09-0.112-1.366,0.366s-0.111,1.09,0.365,1.366c0.479,0.276,1.09,0.113,1.367-0.366C9.821,13.126,9.657,12.516,9.18,12.239zM8.625,17.043c-0.001-0.552-0.448-0.999-1.001-1c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1c0,0.553,0.449,1,1,1C8.176,18.043,8.624,17.596,8.625,17.043zM16.312,3.957V3.031h1c0.275,0,0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5v-0.5c0-0.275-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5h-3.625c-0.275,0-0.5,0.225-0.5,0.5v0.5c0,0.275,0.225,0.5,0.5,0.5h1v0.926C7.819,4.381,2.376,10.068,2.374,17.042C2.376,24.291,8.251,30.166,15.5,30.169c7.249-0.003,13.124-5.878,13.125-13.127C28.624,10.067,23.181,4.38,16.312,3.957zM15.5,27.166C9.909,27.157,5.385,22.633,5.375,17.042C5.385,11.451,9.909,6.927,15.5,6.917c5.59,0.01,10.115,4.535,10.124,10.125C25.615,22.633,21.091,27.157,15.5,27.166zM12.062,22.998c-0.478-0.275-1.089-0.111-1.366,0.367c-0.275,0.479-0.111,1.09,0.366,1.365c0.478,0.277,1.091,0.111,1.365-0.365C12.704,23.887,12.54,23.275,12.062,22.998zM12.062,11.088c0.479-0.276,0.642-0.888,0.366-1.366c-0.276-0.478-0.888-0.642-1.366-0.366s-0.642,0.888-0.366,1.366C10.973,11.2,11.584,11.364,12.062,11.088zM22.822,13.971c0.478-0.275,0.643-0.888,0.366-1.366c-0.275-0.478-0.89-0.642-1.366-0.366c-0.479,0.278-0.642,0.89-0.366,1.367C21.732,14.083,22.344,14.247,22.822,13.971zM15.501,23.92c-0.552,0-1,0.447-1,1c0,0.552,0.448,1,1,1s1-0.448,1-1C16.501,24.367,16.053,23.92,15.501,23.92zM19.938,9.355c-0.477-0.276-1.091-0.111-1.365,0.366c-0.275,0.48-0.111,1.091,0.366,1.367s1.089,0.112,1.366-0.366C20.581,10.245,20.418,9.632,19.938,9.355zM23.378,16.042c-0.554,0.002-1.001,0.45-1.001,1c0.001,0.552,0.448,1,1.001,1c0.551,0,1-0.447,1-1C24.378,16.492,23.929,16.042,23.378,16.042zM22.823,20.115c-0.48-0.275-1.092-0.111-1.367,0.365c-0.275,0.479-0.112,1.091,0.367,1.367c0.477,0.275,1.089,0.112,1.365-0.366C23.464,21.004,23.3,20.391,22.823,20.115zM15.501,8.167c-0.552,0-1,0.448-1,1l-0.466,7.343l-3.004,1.96c-0.478,0.277-0.642,0.889-0.365,1.366c0.275,0.479,0.889,0.642,1.365,0.366l3.305-1.676c0.055,0.006,0.109,0.017,0.166,0.017c0.828,0,1.5-0.672,1.5-1.5l-0.5-7.876C16.501,8.614,16.053,8.167,15.501,8.167zM18.939,22.998c-0.479,0.276-0.643,0.888-0.366,1.367c0.275,0.477,0.888,0.642,1.366,0.365c0.478-0.276,0.642-0.889,0.366-1.365C20.028,22.886,19.417,22.723,18.939,22.998zM11.197,3.593c-0.836-1.04-2.103-1.718-3.541-1.718c-2.52,0-4.562,2.042-4.562,4.562c0,0.957,0.297,1.843,0.8,2.576C5.649,6.484,8.206,4.553,11.197,3.593zM27.106,9.014c0.503-0.733,0.8-1.619,0.8-2.576c0-2.52-2.043-4.562-4.562-4.562c-1.438,0-2.704,0.678-3.541,1.717C22.794,4.553,25.351,6.484,27.106,9.014z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-opacity="1"/>
```

I want this clock to be scaled and occupy all the 200x100 rectangle, but it is not.
I would be very grateful if anybody could help.

Answer (score 1):

From the ['image' element definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#ImageElement) in the SVG 1.1 spec:

> The value of the ‘viewBox’ attribute to use when evaluating the
>   ‘preserveAspectRatio’ attribute is defined by the **referenced content**.
>   For content that clearly identifies a viewBox (e.g. an SVG file with
>   the ‘viewBox’ attribute on the outermost svg element) that value
>   should be used. For most raster content (PNG, JPEG) the bounds of the
>   image should be used (i.e. the ‘image’ element has an implicit
>   ‘viewBox’ of '0 0 raster-image-width raster-image-height'). **Where no
>   value is readily available (e.g. an SVG file with no ‘viewBox’
>   attribute on the outermost svg element) the ‘preserveAspectRatio’
>   attribute is ignored**, and only the translation due to the ‘x’ & ‘y’
>   attributes of the viewport is used to display the content.

What the spec tells you is that the referenced svg (your clock.svg) should define it's coordinate system (aka 'viewBox').

Comment: Thanks, and yes, it works if I do so. However It would be great if it would be possible to scale any svg even if it doesn't have viewBox set. I guess it is not possible...

Comment: Well, there is one possibility... in theory you should be able to reference e.g `clock.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,0,64,64))`. However, it seems the browser compat for that is poor, and besides you'd still just be guessing so it's not really a good solution for this usecase anyway.